# SQL Server: Detect ALTER vs CREATE in trigger text

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have a trigger that is using `CHECKSUM` to compare certain columns between inserted and deleted. On occasion, I need to update which columns are checked so I've created another procedure that reads the trigger text, changes the `CHECKSUM` logic, and issues a new `UPDATE` trigger or DROP/CREATE trigger command to make the change.

Here's my challenge: I don't know whether to issue a `DROP TRIGGER` command first because I can't detect whether the `sysComments.text` represents an `ALTER TRIGGER` or `CREATE TRIGGER` syntax.

I could use something like `PATINDEX('%CREATE%PROC%', @triggerText)` but that would be unreliable as it might pick up comments and other non-appropriate text.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you just create a batch that has first `if (object_id('triggername) is null) create trigger ...` with dummy contents and then always use alter trigger?

Comment: Hi @James - the trigger will always exist before I try to alter it, I just don't know if the text I'm getting back from sys.sql_modules has ALTER or CREATE.  Since I plan to rerun that exact text (just with my changes interpolated in), I would only need to drop the trigger if it's syntax was CREATE, not ALTER.

Answer (score 0):

I really wouldn't rebuild the text of the trigger using string manipulation; or at all really. I would just alter the trigger once to execute whatever the checksum code is you need dynamically. You could maintain a separate table of columns, or even just the literal string of columns elsewhere. Then just concatenate that list into the checksum when you need it. Something like this:

```
if object_id('tempdb.dbo.#ChecksumColumns') is not null drop table #ChecksumColumns
create table #ChecksumColumns
(
    ColumnName nvarchar(128) primary key clustered
)

insert into #ChecksumColumns 
values ('Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3')

declare 
    @sql nvarchar(max),
    @columns nvarchar(max)

select 
    @columns = stuff((select ',' + ColumnName
                      from #ChecksumColumns
                      for xml path('')), 1, 1, ''),
    @Sql = 'select checksum(' + @columns + ')
```

Also just FYI, syscomments has been deprecated in favor of sys.sql_modules. not a big deal but worth making the switch.

Comment: Hey @Xedni - this is a high-traffic table (reads/writes) so performance is critical.  I don't want to have dynamic sql in the trigger, I would like it 100% precompiled.  Even if I deferred the CHECKSUM to say, another function I wouldn't want that function to use any dynamic SQL either.

Comment: @sisdog Re-creating the trigger isn't going to be any better, in fact its probably going to be worse. If you concatenate the sql and use `sp_executesql`, it will cache the plan on there (It's only `exec ('<sql>')` that doesn't cache the execution plan). If you're altering or god forbid dropping and re-creating the trigger, that's going to cause a schema lock on the trigger, AND recompile it.